# What is the "annotate" method in Google Vision API?

Tags: google-api, http-post

I am reading the Google Vision API documentation:
(https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/requests-and-responses)
It says something like the follwing:

```
Currently, the Vision API consists of one collection (images) which supports one HTTP Request method (annotate):
POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate
```

My question is what does it mean by the method "annotate"? Also, how do I read this syntax with the colon ":"? Is this just a notation that Google uses or some kind of industry standard where you use the colon and calling the stuff after a "method"?

I am a financial Java developer but noob to Web/HTTP technology (I have read some basic of GET/POST but that did not seem to help me with this question). If it seems to you that I am totally lacking in some fundamentals, is there any pointer for me to read up some related books/website/tutorial/documentation that can help me understand this better? Any help is appreciated!